# EC2 instance can ping IP address but not a dns address

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a ubuntu ec2 instance in region eu-west-3, in a public subnet.

I am able to run curl on websites successfuly, as well as ping on IP addresses.
However, when I run ping on addresses such as google.com, I have a dns failure error.

Any idea what can be wrong in the configurations of my EC2 instance?

This is the content of /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search eu-west-3.compute.internal
```

And the terraform code:

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 2.21.0"

  name = "${local.env_type}-vpc"
  cidr = local.workspace["net_cidr"]

  azs             = ["eu-west-3a", "eu-west-3b"]
  private_subnets = local.workspace["private_subnets"]
  public_subnets  = local.workspace["public_subnets"]

  enable_nat_gateway           = true
  single_nat_gateway           = true
  reuse_nat_ips                = false
  enable_vpn_gateway           = false
  enable_dns_hostnames         = true
  create_database_subnet_group = true

  enable_ipv6                                    = true
  assign_ipv6_address_on_creation                = true
  private_subnet_assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false

  public_subnet_ipv6_prefixes   = [0, 1]
  private_subnet_ipv6_prefixes  = [2, 3]
  database_subnet_ipv6_prefixes = [4, 5]

  database_subnets = local.workspace["database_subnets"]

  tags = {
    ManagedByTerraform = "true"
    EnvironmentType    = "${local.env_type}"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "public_instance" {
  #vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    protocol  = "tcp"

    # Note that opening to 0.0.0.0/0 can lead to security vulnerabilities.
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port = 8080
    to_port   = 8080
    protocol  = "tcp"

    # Note that opening to 0.0.0.0/0 can lead to security vulnerabilities.
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "ubuntu_vm" {
  ami                  = "ami-064736ff8301af3ee"
  instance_type        = "t3.medium"
  key_name             = "aws-key"
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.instance_pcb_profile.id
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.public_instance.id
  ]
  tags = {
    Name = "pcb-${local.env_type}"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
  vpc      = true
  instance = aws_instance.ubuntu_vm.id
}
```

Comment: Check `/etc/hosts` for any entry for `google.com`. If nothing is there, check `/etc/resolv.conf` for any nameserver entry, it should point to a valid address which is a dns.

Comment: The resolv.conf is generated by symbolic link and I added it in my question. Each time I try to edit it and restart, It is resumed to the original file. I can't add nameserver 8.8.8.8 above nameserver 127.0.0.53

Comment: Check if file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` exists and what is its content.

Comment: You can add nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf/` and then do `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`. It will persist.

Comment: it seems like you have some process running locally(127.0.0.53) which is responsible for resolution, `systemd-resolved` might be the process, check logs for the same and check the resolv status using `resolvectl status`  pay attention to the DNS entries show in that . Check `/etc/nsswitch.conf` . Run `strace` to figure out which configs are being referenced. `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` this has file some options to specify the DNS resolvers too, in the worst case add the necessary entries to this file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` which will be amended to the original one.

Comment: What I don’t understand is that my instance is a very basic EC2 machine in a public subnet of aws, that I tried to recreate several times. And always the same issue. I doubt I need such technical solutions to have a working DNS resolution, no?

Comment: Is dns name resolution enabled in yr vpc? Also what is 127.0.0.53?

Comment: yes it is ! (I checked it several times). For 127.0.0.53, it is a standard nameserver used by AWS, that I saw in a lot of EC2 instances. I just added all the terraform code to have a better vision of the AWS infra

Comment: Also see check this in yr vpc: enableDnsSupport  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support